# GitKraken Staging too slow after upgrade

Tags: staging, gitkraken

So, I've been using gitkraken for awhile and loving it, even considering getting a subscription especially  now that they have another thing called Glo - soon to come.

I have recently upgraded GitKraken to v3.3.4.  I am not sure whether that was a big mistake but things got a little too annoying. Staging takes a very long time, and you can't do anything when gitkraken is staging files.  I read the release notes but there is nothing like this mentioned.  Probably just me but would like to know if anyone has the same issue and have you found a way to fix, if ever.

Comment: What OS are you using?

Comment: Oh, sorry.  am using Ubuntu 16

Comment: Got the same problem on Fedora 28. It was much snappier earlier. I'm using the snap version now. Are you using .deb or snap?

Comment: I'm on GitKraken 4.1.1 on macOS 10.14.2, and as of today GitKraken is extremely slow for me. Staging is taking forever on markdown files! Not sure what's going on, but hoping it'll get fixed.

Answer (score 0):

you can try it in your terminal:

codesign --remove-signature /Applications/GitKraken.app/Contents/Frameworks/GitKraken\ Helper\ (Renderer).app

Comment: Hi there, welcome to stackoverflow. This post is over two years old so I doubt the issues are relevant any longer. For reference it's also good to provide context for your answers (e.g. what your solution does and why the OP should use your solution)

Comment: I still experience this. Gitkraken is extremely slow on my windows 10 machine. I have a colleague with windows 10 who is experiencing the same.

Comment: I am too experiencing this issue.